# How to update a pandas dataframe with Nans inside an Oracle table so that the Nans become NULLs?

Tags: python, sql, pandas, oracle

My pandas dataframe has NAN values.. I am using 'df.dropna' method to drop all the missing values from my dataframe so that I can write it back to my Oracle Database Table.
But inside the DB Table, the Nan values are getting replaced with 0 and i want them to remain Null.
Alternatively, is there any way to update the Oracle Table with a dataframe which contains missing/NaN values. The NaNs should become Null inside the DB.
Please help as I am new to python and pandas.

Comment: df_new = df.where((pd.notnull(df)), None)

Answer (score 1):

I am using for this:

```
df_new = df.where((pd.notnull(df)), None)
```

Example:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
df = pd.DataFrame(['str1', np.nan])
df


0   str1
1   NaN


df_new = df.where((pd.notnull(df)), None)
df_new

0   str1
1   None
```